# Writing to websocket with BLWebSocketsServer

Tags: objective-c, c, websocket, wrapper

Not sure how many of you are familiar with BLWebsocketsServer. Available at: https://github.com/benlodotcom/BLWebSocketsServer.

It's an Objective-C wrapper for LibWebSocket (Written in C). It basically only provides functionality to callback based on what is received from the client.

I'm trying to send data asynchronously to the open web sockets without using the callback that's already written in to the wrapper (as it won't be in response to anything). I presume this has to be written into the wrapper, but I have no idea how!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the support for asynchronous messages (push) in the last version of BLWebSocketsServer. Here is what you need to do to push a message to all your connected clients:

```
//Start the server
[[BLWebSocketsServer sharedInstance] startListeningOnPort:9000 withProtocolName:@"my-protocol-name" andCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Server started");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}];
//Push a message to every connected clients
[[BLWebSocketsServer sharedInstance] pushToAll:[@"pushed message"     dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```